# The application does not respond when you enter the slash command "/invite"

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

when I enter the command "/ invite" writes that "The application is not responding" the screen below
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KljVl.png)

**My code**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_choice, create_option

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)
token = "token"

@slash.slash(name = 'invite', description = '[Отчет о принятии] Принятие человека в семью', options = [{
    "name": "text", 
    "description": "пользователь", 
    "type": 3, 
    "requied": True,
}], guild_ids = [907718567485636668])
async def invite(ctx:SlashContext, member: discord.Member):
  await ctx.send("hello")

client.run(token)
```

**Help please!**

Comment: Do you select the `application.commands` option when you generate your bot invite link at [discord developer portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPvJ5.png)?

Answer (score 0):

This happen if something in the backend is wrong. eg. if the commands are still listed while the bot is offline, this error will happen. However, it can have different reasons depending on the situations. if i were you, i would try to kick the bot and then when generating the invitelink select application.commands. Maybe this solve it. If not just let me know and i'll come up with another solution.